# @WithMockUser returning NoSuchMethodError

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-test

I'm trying to run this test

```
@Test
@WithMockUser(username = "myUser", roles = ["USER"])
fun givenExistingFirstnames_whenGetRequest_thenReturnsFirstnameJsonWithStatus200() {
    every { firstnameService.findFirstnames() } returns firstnames

    mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/firstnames"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk)
        .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.firstname").value("Amadou"))
}
```

but when run, I get this error and I can't understand why:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.authenticated(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.util.Collection)'
```

Here are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.7.3")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:2.7.3")
    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.4.2")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.7.3")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.7.3")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.13.3")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.6.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0")
    implementation("com.sipios:spring-search:0.2.4")
    implementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.9.0")
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-ui
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.10")
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv
    implementation("com.opencsv:opencsv:5.6")
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1")
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.liquibase/liquibase-core
    //implementation("org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.7.1")
    runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2:2.1.214")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.7.3") {
        exclude(group = "org.mockito", module = "mockito-core")
    }
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:5.7.3")
    testImplementation("com.ninja-squad:springmockk:3.1.1")
}
```

It seems that all versions are aligned

Comment: Check the compatibility of the library versions. I guess the spring security lib is not compatible to you spring boot version.

Comment: Yes that was it thanks

I updated spring boot version in my plugin and it works now :

plugins {
 id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.3"